# django Web-Sockets design and in-memory data storage

Tags: django, design-patterns, websocket, django-channels

**Objective:** to provide end-user number of 'notifications' in (almost) real time.

[image]

To keep it simple, notifications should come when userX submits form XYZ and all other users should see that the number of notifications incremented by 1 (if userY see the number 50 that means there are 50 NEW XYZ forms).

**Question #1:** given my django channels web-socket, where should I iterate to get the result? At the moment I placed it under websocket_connect with an endless loop such that:

```
class EchoDiscussionNotificationConsumer(AsyncConsumer):

async def websocket_connect(self, event):

    await self.send({
        "type": "websocket.accept",
    })

    # NOT SURE THIS IS A GOOD DESIGN! 
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        rand = random.randint(1,100)
        mesg = "#"+str(rand)

        await self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.send',
            'text':  mesg,
        })
```

This works great but I don't think this is a good design.

**Question #2:** I don't want to query the db every 2 seconds what I had in mind is to query only when (1) the user logs in and (2) another user submits form XYZ. So once I have a 'table of notifications' from the db where should I store it (in-memory) to have faster access? (session?)

Answer (score 1):

As you already suggested, you should have a `Notification` table. Notifications should be created each time a form is submitted then you can use the notification post_save signal to send notifications to the websocket.

In this way, you won't have to long-poll the DB as that defeats the purpose of websockets.

As for where to save the notifications, the DB is quite enough in this case unless you have a very high load.